# How to make human readable transaction from custom/private Gnosis Safe Apps

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are developing a custom/private Safe App for our team Gnosis Safe, and one "issue" we noticed is that the transactions submitted to the Gnosis Safe from the Safe App are not "human-readable".

I read in the documentation that for verified Safe Apps, transactions are made "human-readable" after the contract is verified on Sourcify. Would it also work for custom/private Safe Apps? Does the Gnosis Safe UI check automatically if the contract is verified on Sourcify and load its ABI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the Gnosis Safe UI check automatically if the contract is verified on Sourcify and load its ABI?

Yes, it does. ABI is loaded based on contract address, it's not associated with an app in any way. More info: https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4971390-submit-an-abi

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Will this also work for upgradable contracts? (i.e. proxy contracts)